# ACS Data Interpretation

Tags: united-states, census, population, demography

I am working with ACS 5-Year Data at the block group level in ArcGIS, and was hoping someone could explain what one of the elements on my attribute table means.

[image]

I know that the B00001e1 is some type of population estimate, but I am confused about whether or not it is a population estimate change, or population estimate totals for each block group.

Comment: If it's open data that you are asking about then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this stack! I'm going to post there now too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the variable list at https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2013ACS/Metadata/BG_Metadata_2013.txt, it should be the unweighted estimate of the total population.

Comment: Yeah, that's what confuses me about this variable. It says unweighted estimate of total population, but the data ranges from about 2013-2017/8. Is it supposed to be an estimate of all of those years combined?

Comment: I'd assume so, if the data is aggregated its generally safe to assume the data is as well. If the values look weird, is it worth trying to download yearly census's and comparing the values that way? (Not sure how readily available American census data is).

Comment: Ah I see. I'm trying to estimate population change over time, so aggregated in that way is unhelpful. Thanks for your help.